# how to add the value of two radio button?

Tags: android, radio-group

I have two radioGroups that each contain an indeterminate number of radioButton I would like to add the value of the radioButton selected in the radioGroup 1 with the value of the radioButton select in the radioGroup 2 and display the result in a toast. I try the code below but it does not seem to work

How can I do this please?

What I try:

```
RadioButton lamp1;
RadioButton tele1;
RadioGroup group, group2;
Button button;
int result;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_type_installation);

    addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    group = findViewById(R.id.group);
    group2 = findViewById(R.id.group2);

    ampoule1 = findViewById(R.id.lamp1);
    tele1 = findViewById(R.id.tele1);

    button = findViewById(R.id.calcul);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int selectedId = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            int selectedId1 = group2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            ampoule1 = findViewById(selectedId);
            tele1 = findViewById(selectedId1);

            result = selectedId+selectedId1;
            Toast.makeText(Type_Installation.this, "your consommation is"
                    +result+"W", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

XML code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ampoule"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appBar"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:text="Ampoule"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ampoule"
    android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_700"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"/>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ampoule"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/lamp1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="40 W"
        android:checked="true"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/lamp2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="60 W"
        android:textColor="@color/material_blue_grey_700"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/lamp3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="75 W"
        android:textColor="@color/material_blue_grey_700"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/ampoule4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="100 W"
        android:textColor="@color/material_blue_grey_700"/>
</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tele"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/group"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:text="Televiseur"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tele"
    android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_700"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"/>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/group2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tele"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/tele1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="100 W"
        android:checked="true"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/tele2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="200 W"
        android:textColor="@color/material_blue_grey_700"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/tele3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="300 W"
        android:textColor="@color/material_blue_grey_700"/>
</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/calcul"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/material_button1"
    android:text="calculer"/>
```

Comment: you want to show toast when you select one of the radio button

Comment: no when I click on the "calculate" button

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used these lines of code

```
 lamp1 = findViewById(selectedId);
  tele1 = findViewById(selectedId1);
  result = Integer.valueOf(lamp1.getText().toString())+Integer.valueOf(tele1.getText().toString());
```

Instead of this

```
ampoule1 = findViewById(selectedId);
tele1 = findViewById(selectedId1);
 result = selectedId+selectedId1;
```

Comment: Note that your text is not pure integers. I would make your radio buttons have text values that are only Integers. Then this will work

Comment: Thanks for correction. I thought radio button values are integers because he is adding String value in Toast Toast.makeText(Type_Installation.this, "your consommation is"
                    +result+"W", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Answer (score 0):

You can first get the ids of selected `radio button` from the radio groups, then after getting ids, you can get the text of selected `radio button`, then you can add them or do what ever you want.

Below code assumes that your `radio buttons` are having integer value as text `i.e 5,6,7`

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // get selected radio button from radioGroup
        int selectedId1 = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        int selectedId2 = group2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        // find the radiobutton by returned id
        RadioButton radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId1);
        RadioButton radioButton2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId2);


        //Assuming text on radio buttons are integer values like 5.6.7 etc

        int result = Integer.parseInt(radioButton1.getText())+Integer.parseInt(radioButton2 .getText());


        Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
            "Resulkt"+result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.